# Put properties with different name in one field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am getting requests from different devices as Json. Some of them show temperature as "T", some other as "temp" and it can be different in other devices. is that possible to define in MongoDB to put all of these values in single field "temperature"?

Doesn't matter if it is "temp" or "T" or "tempC", just put all of them in "temperature" field.

Here is an example of my data:

```json
[
 { "ip": "12:3B:6A:1A:E6:8B", "type": 0, "t": 37},
 { "ip": "22:33:66:1A:E6:8B", "type": 1, "temperature": 40},
 { "ip": "1A:3C:6A:1A:E6:8B", "type": 1, "temp": 30}
]
```

I want to put `temp`, `t` and `temperature` in `Temperature` field in my collection.

Comment: Please show your sample data

Comment: Please consider something like this, [{
      "ip": "12:3B:6A:1A:E6:8B",
      "type": 0,
      "t": 37},{
      "ip": "22:33:66:1A:E6:8B",
      "type": 1,
      "temperature": 40},{
      "ip": "1A:3C:6A:1A:E6:8B",
      "type": 1,
      "temp": 30}] -  I want to put temp, t, temperature in Temperature field in my collection.

Comment: Hi M. Taherian, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I've taken the liberty of copying your example data into the question itself; remember, on this site you are encouraged to [edit] and re-edit your question as necessary, to improve it as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you Vince Bowdren, it is really better. I will do that in next questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator to control which value should be transferred into your output, like below:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: { Temperature: { $ifNull: [ { $ifNull: [ "$t", "$temperature"] }, "$temp" ] } }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            t: 0,
            temperature: 0,
            temp: 0
        }
    }
])
```

This will merge that three fields into one `Temperature` taking first not empty value. Additionally if you want to update your collection, you can add [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) as a last aggregation stage like `{ $out: col }` but keep in mind that it will entirely replace your source collection.

Comment: Thank you mickl, this is what exactly I was looking for.

Comment: When should I use this? before insert? Could you please show this in document insertion.

Comment: @M.Taherian you mean you want to update your whole collection or just unify your query results ?

Comment: I want to unify it when I insert it in collection. Define which one is not null and insert it in Temperature field when I am inserting the object.

Comment: @M.Taherian this should be handled outside of mongodb in your application logic. Otherwise you can keep you current code and use above solution when you query your collection.

Answer (score 0):

I think mongodb supports regular expression but they are meant to search datas, not to insert them based on fieldname matches.
I am quite sure you shall use some kind of facade in front of your database to achieve that.

Comment: Thank you, regular expression doesn't work in this case.